# Imports not working in command prompt and VSCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, import

Heres my code:

```
import praw

#do something
```

Whenever I run this in either VS Code or command prompt I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\12488\Downloads\Reddit\post.py", line 3, in <module>
    r = praw.Reddit(user_agent="My user agent")
  File "C:\Users\12488\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 249, in __init__
    raise MissingRequiredAttributeException(
praw.exceptions.MissingRequiredAttributeException: Required configuration setting 'client_id' missing.
This setting can be provided in a praw.ini file, as a keyword argument to the `Reddit` class constructor, or as an environment variable.
```

I thought maybe this was just a problem with praw so I tried reinstalling praw as well as installing different versions using commands I found on other forums, in the end I just tried importing other modules I commonly use like discord.py, cv2 and moviepy and none of those work either. Since finding what's wrong is a pretty broad question, please do not hesitate to ask for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with `praw`, But the error prompt shows you just missed `client_id`. And I find an example in the official docs, it provid`client_id` attribute.

```
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id="my client id",
    client_secret="my client secret",
    user_agent="my user agent",
)
```